# Updating a frame on RadioButton click using java

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm using html frames, splitting the page into 4 parts. The top left part is used to show several database fact tables, organized in a RadioButton group, allowing the user to specify the table which he's interested in. Upon selection, dimension tables linked to the selected table are displayed in the bottom left frame. The function of the remaining two tables is not important right now.

I have a servlet tending to each frame, and have managed to get the first frame up and running. What I would like to do now is to call the second servlet each time a new RadioButton is clicked and have it update its' frame. I tried the onClick approach with no success, and resorting to forms in order to allow updates via submit buttons seems a bit lackluster.

In short, I'd like to call another servlet each time a new RadioButton selection is made in the browser.

Update:
Here's the current solution.

```
<%@ page session="true" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="/DZ4/dimensionsAndMeasures" target="dimAndMes">
<ol>
    <c:forEach var="table" items="${factTables}">
        <li><input type="radio" name="factTable" value="${table.id}" onclick="this.form.submit()">${table.name}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ol>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you show us the code, you want to do?

Comment: @user23123412 I have updated the original post with the current solution, i.e. using a form and triggering its' submit() by radio button click. It does work, but if you have a better solution in mind please do share.